# Increasing the size of the title of a plotly graphic

Tags: r, plotly

I'm using `plotly 4.5.2`.

Here is how I do to change the size of the title of the plot, by using `titlefont=list(size=30)` in `layout()`:

```
library(plotly)
x <- 0:10
y <- 0:10
dd <- transform(expand.grid(x=x, y=y), z=x+y)
dd1 <- data.frame(x=x, y=y) 
pp <- plot_ly() %>% 
  layout(title="Hello", titlefont=list(size=30)) %>%
  add_trace(data=dd, x=~x, y=~y, z=~z, type="heatmap") %>% 
  add_trace(data=dd1, x=~x, y=~y, type="scatter", mode="lines", showlegend=FALSE)
```

But then the title is not correctly rendered when it is too big:

[image]

Is it a bug, or am I doing something bad ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set a graph size manually. Try the following:
`pp %>% layout(autosize = F, height = 500, margin = list(l=50, r=50, b=100, t=100, pad=4))`

[Title is visible now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvz1c.jpg)